# Is it known that Clifford circuits are not universal for classical computation?

Tags: clifford-group, universal-gates, reversible-computation

I'm interested in whether there is some known result about Clifford circuits being insufficent for classical computation.

Aaronson and Gottesman in their 2004 paper [Improved Simulation of Stabilizer Circuits](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0406196.pdf) say the following...

> Since stabilizer circuits are a generalization of CNOT
> circuits, it is obvious that Gottesman-Knill is ⊕L-
> hard (i.e. any ⊕L problem can be reduced to it). Our result says that Gottesman-Knill is in ⊕L. Intuitively,
> this means that any stabilizer circuit can be simulated
> efficiently using CNOT gates alone the additional availability of Hadamard and phase gates gives stabilizer circuits at most a polynomial advantage. In our view, this
> surprising fact helps to explain the Gottesman-Knill theorem, by providing strong evidence that stabilizer circuits
> are not even universal for classical computation

They prove this $\oplus L$ completeness result in section V of their paper.

Is it now proven that Clifford circuits are not sufficent for classical computation? In the paper Aaronson and Gottesman provide evidence for this but not a full proof as far as I know.

Comment: See also https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/32332/where-does-the-clifford-circuits-stand-in-the-complexity-hierarchy and in particular Craig Gidney's answer therein. However, I think there is no formal proof that they are not universal (although it is strongly believed).

Comment: Ah thank you @MarkusHeinrich. This seems very relevant for my question.